# Thickbox not functioning when placed using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, load, thickbox

First let me say that I learned scripting by myself so my approaches may be a bit weird.

I want to call images into a div using AJAX but with a thickbox tag so when the image thumb is clicked the big image is displayed using the Thickbox (jQuery).

Here is the example page: [click here](http://www.dinomuhic.com/2010/test2.php)

OK, please click in the menue on "photo" and then open one of the images in the left menue, for example "dusk". The dusk image will be placed in the main box. 
Now I want to open the image using Thickbox when you click on it. But it doesn't work, it just opens  the image in the same window.

However the Thickbox is working properly if I just add an image to the test2.php like this:

```
<a href="images/test1.jpg" class="thickbox" rel="gallery"><img id="images" src="images/test1.jpg" alt="Single Image" /></a>
```

Here's how my backend is structured.
All needed js-files (jQuery, thickbox, etc) are intergrated into the test2.php

When one of the links in the photo menue is clicked an AJAX call is sent to getwork.php with the ID of the photo.

```
function createRequestObject()
{
var ro;
var browser = navigator.appName;
if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
    {
    ro = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
    else
    {
    ro = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
return ro;

}

var http = createRequestObject();

var katcheck;

function sndReq(req)
{

var req2 = req;

katcheck = req.slice(0, 1);

   if (katcheck == "k")
   {
   var katid = req2.slice(3,4);

   http.open('get', 'getkat.php?kat='+katid);
   http.send(null);
   http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
   }
   else
   {

   if(startcheck==true){ var param = req;
                            http.open('get', 'getwork.php?id='+param);
                            http.send(null);
                            http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;}
   else{
     $('#videoleft')
      .animate(  {"left": "-800px"},
                600, 'easeInQuad',
                function(){

                            var param = req;
                            http.open('get', 'getwork.php?id='+param);
                            http.send(null);
                            http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
                          } // this is the callback function
             )
      .animate(
                {"top": "0px", "left": "800px"},
                { queue:true, duration:1},
                function(){$(this).hide();}
             );
   }
  }
 }



 function handleResponse()
 {
    if(http.readyState == 4)
                    {
                   var response = http.responseText;

      if (katcheck == "k")
      {

                document.getElementById("videomenue").innerHTML = response;
                $("#videomenue").animate({"top": "0px", "left": "0px"},{ queue:true, duration:1}).show(500);
                $('#videoleft').css('float', 'right');
      }
      else
      {
      document.getElementById("post").innerHTML = response;

      if(startcheck==true){ startcheck=false;}
      else
      {
        $('#videoleft').show().animate({"top": "0px", "left":"0px"},{ queue:true, duration:800,  easing: 'easeOutBack'});
      }
      }
    }


  }
```

OK and now what happens in the getwork.php:

```
{
$imgecho = ('<div class="img"><a href="'.$src.'?height=300&width=300modal=true" class="thickbox" rel="gallery"><img src="'.$image.'" width="'.$width1.'" height="'.$heightpic.'" alt="'.$row['title'].'" style="border: solid 1px grey;" /></a></div>');
}
 echo ('<div class="titleBG"></div><p class="title">'.$row['title'].'</p>'.$imgecho.''); break;
```

I of course stripped it down to only the important part. The php file is working properly but somehow no of the applied tags needed for thickbox are working. 
I even added the `?height=300&width=300modal=true` like advised on the Thickbox website but it isnt working.
I can't explain it to myself and it's already bugging me for a long time.

I hope someone can help me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the `tb_init` method manually after setting up the content, for instance, after setting the `innerHTML` of `#videomenue` call this:

```
tb_init('#videomenue a.thickbox');
```

And after the `#post` call:

```
tb_init('#post a.thickbox');
```

**Also:** You are jumping through a ton of unnecessary hoops since you are already using jQuery. For instance, here was a fast rewrite of all the code you posted, using just jQuery. If you have made the decision to use jQuery, try to use as much of it as possible to clean up your code (as a general practice):

```
function sndReq(req){
  var req2 = req,
  katcheck = req.slice(0, 1);

  var handleResponse = function(data){
    if(data){
      if(katcheck == "k"){
        $("#videomenue")
          .html( data )
          .animate({"top": "0px", "left": "0px"},{ queue:true, duration:1}).show(500);
        tb_init('#videomenue a.thickbox');
        $('#videoleft').css('float', 'right');
      } else {
        $("#post").html( data );
        tb_init('#post a.thickbox');
        if(startcheck == true){ 
          startcheck = false;
        } else {
          $('#videoleft').show().animate({"top": "0px", "left":"0px"},{ queue:true, duration:800,  easing: 'easeOutBack'});
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if( katcheck == "k" ){
    var katid = req2.slice(3,4);
    $.get('getwork.php', { kat: katid }, handleResponse );
  } else {
    var param = req;
    if( startcheck == true ){
      $.get('getwork.php', { id: param }, handleResponse );
    } else {
      $('#videoleft')
        .animate( {"left": "-800px"}, 600, 'easeInQuad',
            function(){ $.get('getwork.php', { id: param }, handleResponse ); })
        .animate( {"top": "0px", "left": "800px"}, {queue:true, duration:1},
            function(){ $(this).hide(); });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! It works (after one small correction)! You can see it if you want on the test3.php page in the same directory! I know that jQuery is able to do what I need I just didn't figured out how to solve the AJAX thing with it, so I kept my old AJAX code to get the data. I will now try to understand your code. Thanks!

Comment: @Pekka when Thickbox calls its own init, it makes this call `tb_init('a.thickbox, area.thickbox, input.thickbox')` Which tells it where to look. By calling it again, and scoping the search to the element that just had its `html` fully replaced, there should be no issue.

Comment: @Anti-Depressiva Glad I could help, and good luck with your project!

Comment: @Pekka. Yes thickbox seems to do that. You can see it right at the top of the JS file: http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/thickbox-code/thickbox.js 
Now that thickbox is working I will try to change the photo section of my site in the way that it display all photos as thumbs in the main box at once so that I don't need the left menue at all.

Comment: (slapping head) it's scoping it in the init. I totally overlooked that, sorry. I'm removing my comment.

Answer (score 2):

As most Lightbox clones, Thickbox initializes on `load` of the main document. It looks for all `<a>`elements that have the required class, and adds the necessary events to them. Elements introduced into the document later will *not* automatically turn into thickbox links.

You will have to run the Thickbox initialization command every time you introduce a new element, or find out how to initialize a specific element.

Comment: Thank you very much for that information. I didn't knew that!